# Function calling incorrect values

Tags: python, function, recursion

Here's my function, the  important line is where i call f() again.

```
def f(num,xyz,possible,temp):
    y = num%9
    x = num-y
    print num
    for xyz[num] in possible[num]:
        if ispossibility(temp,xyz[num],x,y) == True:
            temp[num] = xyz[num]
            if num != 80:
                f(num+1,xyz,possible,temp) # i call f() with num incremented
            else:
                print 'yes'
                exit()
```

The output of the program is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
3
2
3
3
```

The problem is that whenever the function f() is called, the variable num should always be incremented by 1. But from the output, f() is called with num as 3, when it was previously eight. And so i am wondering how that is possible (the output should be 9 btw, and not 3) when f() is always called w/ num incremented by 1. I've been looking at this function for some time now and i really don't understand what is happening.

Comment: What are the initial values for the arguments. In other words: how your initial call looks like? Is it `f(0, ..., ..., ...)` with what in place of `...`s? Also: please give us `ispossibility` function.

Comment: What is the line `for xyz[num] in possible[num]:` intended to do?  I'm not sure I've ever seen that before.

Comment: DSM i'm trying to make a sudoku solver, and so possible has all the possible numbers for their respective boxes. So it looks like this possible = [[1,2],[2,4,2]...] and so on until possible[80], which has the possibilities for the last box. After looking at my code, i believe that using xyz[num] is not necessary bc i'm calling a function so the variable is going to be local anyway. But in case you don't understand xyz[num] is used to try all the possible permutations of the boxes in possible. I think i know of a better/more understandable way of doing it now. So thanks DSM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `f(num+1, ...)` inside of a loop, so it is possible to call `f()` with the same value for `num` multiple times.